# Python 3 Using Counter to return a count of values with their associated User IDs

Tags: python

Wondering if anyone can help me with this(it is a small extract of a coursework task).

I am trying to return each UserID(visitor_uuid) with their corresponding total time reading(event_readtime).

The data is coming from an already parsed JSON file and my code so far is below:

```
def time_reading(data):
    time = Counter()
    users = Counter()

    for d in data:
        #users[d["visitor_uuid"]] += time[d["event_readtime"]]
        if "event_readtime" in d:

            #Increment the visitor_country in the counter
            final = ([d["visitor_uuid"]],[sum(d["event_readtime"]]))
            #time[d["event_readtime"]] += 1





    return (final)
```

An example of my JSON is:

> {   "ts": 1393631989,    "visitor_uuid": "64bf70296wa2f9fd",
>   "visitor_username": null,    "visitor_source": "internal",
>   "visitor_device": "browser",    "visitor_useragent": "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0",
>   "visitor_ip": "06f49269e749a837",    "visitor_country": "VE",
>   "visitor_referrer": "64f729926497515c",    "env_type": "reader",
>   "env_doc_id": "130705172251-3a2a725b2bbd5aa3f2af810acf0aeabb",
>   "env_adid": null,    "event_type": "pagereadtime",
>   "event_readtime": 5,    "subject_type": "doc",    "subject_doc_id":
>   "130705172251-3a2a725b2bbd5aa3f2af810acf0aeabb",    "subject_page":
>   10,    "cause": null } {   "ts": 1393631989,    "visitor_uuid":
>   "64bf70296wa2f9fd",    "visitor_username": null,    "visitor_source":
>   "internal",    "visitor_device": "browser",    "visitor_useragent":
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/27.0",    "visitor_ip": "06f49269e749a837",
>   "visitor_country": "VE",    "visitor_referrer": "64f729926497515c",
>   "env_type": "reader",    "env_doc_id":
>   "130705172251-3a2a725b2bbd5aa3f2af810acf0aeabb",    "env_adid": null, 
>   "event_type": "pagereadtime",    "event_readtime": 2,
>   "subject_type": "doc",    "subject_doc_id":
>   "130705172251-3a2a725b2bbd5aa3f2af810acf0aeabb",    "subject_page":
>   10,    "cause": null }

and the output would be:

```
(64bf70296wa2f9fd, 7)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You understand that you're supposed to complete your coursework yourself, right?

Comment: im attempting to but i'm looking for some help regarding the task, I posted here to see if anyone can point me in the right directions to do the task as i am struggling

Comment: This isn't a tutorial service. Take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: @JonathanCraig You need to post a sample of your input json and expected output.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ... How did you figure out it's a coursework? .. :)

Comment: i have added an example of my JSON. I do mention in the question that it is part of a coursework task. I dont wish to offend anyone, im just asking if anyone could assist me in letting me know any uses in python that are able to achieve what i need to achieve in the task.

Comment: @IronFist OP says it "it is a small extract of a coursework task".

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there.  This is a classic groupby problem, where you have a user with multiple events.  You don't use a counter here, use a groupby.

Ingredients

```
>>> import random
>>> import operator as op
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> import uuid
```

This snippet gives me similar data to yours

```
>>> data = [{'event_readtime': random.randint(0, 10), 'visitor_uuid': str(uuid.uuid4())} for _ in range(5)]
>>> data
[{'visitor_uuid': 'f6b55181-d3c9-4699-9fac-506b8cc6871c', 'event_readtime': 0}, {'visitor_uuid': '54a24574-1e83-45ab-b4bb-41a0ead3d244', 'event_readtime': 10}, {'visitor_uuid': '3a2fffe9-c173-4afa-b93e-a60b04f043cb', 'event_readtime': 10}, {'visitor_uuid': 'b008557d-c5a1-404a-ba5b-2ec57340dee7', 'event_readtime': 4}, {'visitor_uuid': '6bb94313-4d5e-4339-b3b0-93e9733b4a88', 'event_readtime': 4}]
```

`groupby` only groups adjacent data, so you need to sort them by a key.

```
>>> data.sort(key=op.itemgetter('visitor_uuid'))
```

Then apply a groupby on the dataset

```
>>> [(k, sum(map(op.itemgetter('event_readtime'), v))) for k, v in groupby(data, op.itemgetter('visitor_uuid'))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try using groupby and let you know how i get on!